# Excel Remove Duplicates - which occurrence is kept?

Tags: microsoft-excel, duplicate

In Excel, when removing duplicate rows while ignoring certain columns (`Data` → `Data Tools` → `Remove Duplicates` → unselect ignored columns), some of the values in the ignored columns disappear entirely. Which ones are kept? The first occurrence of each duplicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first occurrence is kept. The page [Filter for unique values or remove duplicate values](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-for-unique-values-or-remove-duplicate-values-ccf664b0-81d6-449b-bbe1-8daaec1e83c2) says:

> When duplicates are removed, the first occurrence of the value in the list is kept, but other identical values are deleted.

Comment: https://superuser.com/help/self-answer